# Implementation of instance testing in Java, C++, C#

Tags: java, c#, c++, inheritance

For curiosity purposes as well as understanding what they entail in a program, I'm curious as to how instance testing (`instanceof`/`is`/using `dynamic_cast` in c++) works.  I've tried to google it (particularly for java) but the only pages that come up are tutorials on how to use the operator.

How do the implementations vary across those langauges?  How do they treat classes with identical signatures?

Also, it's been drilled into my head that using instance testing is a mark of bad design.  Why exactly is this?  When is that applicable, instanceof should still be used in methods like `.equals()` and such right?

I was also thinking of this in the context of exception handling, again particularly in Java.  When you have mutliple `catch` statements, how does that work?  Is that instance testing or is it just resolved during compilation where each thrown exception would go to?

Comment: I've never heard this term used in the context of C#.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm referring to the `is` keyword, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx

Comment: OK.  But what does the `is` keyword have to do with [whatever "instance testing" is](https://www.google.com/search?q=instance%20testing)?

Comment: I downvoted your question because the implementation details vary substantially between languages and even different versions of the same language. The "accepted answer" doesn't even begin to cover two-thirds of the question.

Comment: Related reading: [vtables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). Does not answer your question, but is a good link for people to read who are not familiar with the topic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I explained what I meant by that term, I'm unfamiliar if there's some sort of well known terminology for it, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm curious as to how instance testing (instanceof/is/using dynamic_cast in c++) works

In Java, each object stores a pointer to its type. Each type knows its parent types, so it's straightforward to enumerate all ancestor types. `x instanceof T` iff we encounter `T` during the search.

Similarly, in C++, objects of classes with virtual methods will store a pointer to a `type_info`:

> Every virtual table shall contain one entry that is a pointer to an object derived from `std::type_info`. ([source](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#rtti))

(This is gcc-specific though; I don't know about other compilers.)

> Also, it's been drilled into my head that using instance testing is a mark of bad design. Why exactly is this? When is that applicable, instanceof should still be used in methods like .equals() and such right?

The idea is that, when possible, it's preferable to use polymorphism rather than checking for specific subtypes. It tends to be more elegant, and there's no possibility of forgetting to update our subtype checks when we add a new subtype.

Totally contrived example: say we have `Animal` with subtypes `Lion`, etc. If we want to check if `Animal a` is a carnivore, we could write `a instanceof Lion || a instanceof Bear || ...`, but it would be cleaner and safer to add an `abstract boolean isCarnivore();` in `Animal`.

But I agree, `instanceof` is still appropriate in `equals` since the API forces us to deal with `Object`s.

> When you have mutliple catch statements, how does that work? Is that instance testing or is it just resolved during compilation where each thrown exception would go to?

In Java, it's not possible for a compiler to precompute each exception's path because new exception classes could be loaded at runtime.

The compiler does generate an "exception table" for each try/catch block, where a row in the table contains an exception type and a `pc` offset which should be applied if that exception is encountered. But if you declare `catch (IOException)`, the exception table will only contain `IOException`, not subclasses like `EOFException`. An `instanceof`-like check has to be done at runtime to check if a thrown exception is an `IOException`.

Comment: Thank you, very insightful.  Are you familiar at all with how exceptions/`dynamic_cast` work in c++?  I suppose that might be a little easier to research.  I figured Java would have some sort of information like that in its object references though hah, thanks for clarifying that for me.

Comment: I added a bit of info on C++, though it's still an incomplete answer; I'll expand it more later.